# Set focus on input field when I click on a piece of text

Tags: angular

I am trying to set my focus to an input field when I click on a piece of text on the same page. What is the bext way I can go about this? I already have a method that is attached to the text element. Here is my code.

*HTML*

```
<form-input
    appOskInput
    (inputChanged)="onInputChanged($event,'accountNumber')"
    (blurChanged)="onBlurChanged($event)"
    [formStatus]="formStatus"
    [parentFormGroup]="setupForm"
    [data]="{
      formControlName: 'accountNumber',
      name: 'accountNumber',
      label: Accounnt Number
    }">
</form-input>

<a (click)="isKeyboardActive()" class="use-kepypad"><img class="mouse-icon" src="assets/images/ford/mouse-computer.png"> <img class="mouse-icon" src="assets/images/ford/mouse-computer-hover.png">{{ 'preLogon.common.label.useKeypad'|translate }}</a>
```

*TS*

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.setupForm = new FormGroup({accountNumber: new FormControl('', { validators: [Validators.required, CommonValidators.isValidNumber], updateOn: 'blur' })
}

isKeyboardActive() {
  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get hold of the `form-input` input element using `ViewChid` inside the consumer component by passing `FormInputComponent` class.

And once you get hold of `form-input` element, then you can easily query and focus on `input` element present inside `form-input` control.

```
@ViewChild(FormInputComponent, { read: ElementRef }) formInput: ElementRef;

isKeyboardActive() {
   const input = this.formInput.nativeElement.querySelector('input');
   input.focus();
}
```

[**Stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-custom-form-input-smwydb)